# Mapreduce tasks not running in parallel in pseudodistributed hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am using hadoop on a single node cluster in pseudodistributed mode. My system has 16 cores, but hadoop only runs one map or reduce task at a time, thus not fully utilizing all the cores. I changed the conf/mapred-site.xml to the following but it still doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what can be the problem and its solution.

```
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
        <value>localhost:9001</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
        <value>4</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
        <value>4</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>mapred.map.tasks</name>
        <value>4</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
        <value>4</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Version of Hadoop? Did you restart your JobTracker after the changes?

Comment: Hadoop version is 2.5.2. Did everything in the bag including stopping and restarting all daemons of hadoop, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If the file size you are analyzing is less than the block size (`dfs.blocksize` in hdfs-default.xml) then the file is not splited and only one map task is run, despite of the number of mappers you have configured. Try analyzing bigger files or reducing the block size; several splits will be created, as well as the same amount of mappers.

Answer (score 0):

It is certain that hadoop dispatches one mapper for every input split. By default input split size is equal to the dfs block size which is by default 64MB.

I believe that the size of input file that the job takes should be <= to the input split size.This could be the reason you are seeing one mapper prepared for the job.

To have more than one mapper to proces the file, assign lesser values to the mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize property in your job configuration.

The mapred.map.tasks property is just a hint for the input format, not required to be applied. The mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum property is just used to mention upper bound for # mappers.

To decide the number of reducers requires lots of information. The below link will help you http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces